# Why can't I do this in app delegate?

Tags: ios, uiapplication

```
UIWindow *second = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
NSMutableArray *wArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows];
[wArray addObject:second];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setValue:wArray forKey:@"windows"];
```

This code crashed after KVC. I just want to test UIApplication's windows property.

Comment: Remember to format your code within code tags (the {} on the toolbar)

Comment: The `windows` property is read-only. Why are you trying to set it through `setValue:forKey:`?

Comment: Thanks! I will care this next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Application.h** class you will find about **window**

```
@property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSArray<__kindof UIWindow *>  *windows;
```

which clearly says that **windows** are readonly. So, you cant set/override any value for **windows**.

Comment: UINavigationController's navigationBar and UITabBarController's tabBar.They are both readonly,but they can replace by custom bar through KVC. I don't

Comment: if you write [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows = wArray;

Comment: same error will show for self.navigationController.navigationBar = navBar;

Comment: actually you don't customise "navigation bar" but you can do "self.navigationItem.titleView = customView;" which you may demand to customise "Navigation Bar"